# What is difference between: CamelContext vs ExtendedCamelContext vs SpringCamelContext?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

SpringBoot + ApacheCamel
I have problem with *CamelContext I got exception:

```
Cannot cast org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext to org.apache.camel.ExtendedCamelContext
```

during initialization some components.
parto of my configuration (pom.xml):

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

...

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.25.2</version>
</dependency>

...
```

Question: How to use these context / which one should be used ?

- `CamelContext` aka `DefaultCamelContext`
- `ExtendedCamelContext`
- `SpringCamelContext`

Comment: You are likely mixing Camel versions because ExtendedCamelContext was added to Camel 3.x, but your example shows you are using camel-spring-boot-starter 2.25.2. Try to make sure you use a consistent camel version for all of the camel dependencies in your project.